# Haskell/Kansas Lava shift register errors

Tags: haskell, hdl, lava

I got a piece of code from a kansas-lava paper, that works.

```
counter :: Signal CLK Bool -> Signal CLK Bool -> Signal CLK Int
counter restart inc = loop
  where
    reg = register 0 loop
    reg' = mux restart (0, reg)
    loop = mux inc (reg' + 1, reg')
```

Now I tried to do the same in another function, with another functionality, this doesn't work.

```
shiftReg_d2f :: Signal CLK Bool -> Signal CLK Bool -> [Signal CLK Bool] -> [Signal CLK Bool] -> [Signal CLK Bool]
shiftReg_d2f load shift wordIn fieldIn = fieldOut
  where
    fieldOut = register 0 fieldOut''
    shiftField = drop (length wordIn) fieldOut ++ wordIn
    fieldOut' = muxl shift fieldOut shiftField
    fieldOut'' = muxl load fieldOut' fieldIn
```

Now I'm getting the following errors:

- Couldn't match expected type `[Signal i0 Bool]` with actual type `Signal clk0 a0` (3x)
- Couldn't match expected type `Signal i0 Bool` with actual type `[Signal i0 Bool]`
- Couldn't match expected type `Signal i Bool -> Signal i Bool -> Signal i Bool` with actual type `Signal i Bool`

What do I do wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing up `Signal clk [a]` with `[Signal clk a]`. The former is basically unworkable in the HDL setting since its width is unbounded and could change from cycle to cycle.

What you can do instead is define `fieldOut` wire-by-wire. The key insight is that given inputs

```
fieldIn =  [x0, x1, x2, x3]
wordIn =   [w0, w1, w2]
fieldOut = [y0, y1, y2, y3]
```

your output needs to be one of

```
if load:   [x0, x1, x2, x3] = fieldIn
if shift:  [y3, w0, w1, w2] = drop (lenght wordIn) fieldOut ++ wordIn
otherwise: [y0, y1, y2, y3] = fieldOut
```

So by zipping over `fieldIn` and `drop (length wordIn) fieldOut ++ wordIn` we can generate it bit by bit:

```
shiftReg_d2f :: Signal CLK Bool -> Signal CLK Bool -> [Signal CLK Bool] -> [Signal CLK Bool] -> [Signal CLK Bool]
shiftReg_d2f load shift wordIn fieldIn = fieldOut
  where
    fieldOut = zipWith toOutput fieldIn (drop (length wordIn) fieldOut ++ wordIn)
    toOutput input shifted = r
      where
        r = register False $ mux load (mux shift (r, shifted), input)
```